# How to change color of button when clicked in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, button, windows-phone-7

In WP7 whenever a button is clicked ,the background of button becomes white showing that button is clicked and becomes normal on releasing the mouse button.But I want to change the color of button selection from white to orange.How can i dot it?

Comment: Do you want to style a toggle button?

Comment: I want the color of button on clicking goes orange and when mouse button is released after clicking it again goes to normal.

Comment: I't possible to make this programmatically in C# without XAML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are going to have to play with `Visual States` of that `Button` control. Following is the default style for `Button` extracted from `Expression Blend`:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You will need to change the `Pressed` visual state to:

(In this case background is changed to `Red` when the button is pressed)

```
<VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Comment: does Border have its own VisualState ?

Answer (score 11):

If you're developing for Windows phone, Blend is free and it's an incredibly powerful. I would go so far as to say mandatory, I highly recommend you use it. In Blend it's a simple matter of editing the "Pressed" state style.

1. In Visual studio, in Solution Explorer, right click on your XAML page and select "open in Expression Blend"
2. Right Click on the button -> Edit Template -> Create Copy (Just choose the defaults for the save dialogue)
3. Click on the "states" tab: (You'll see a list of all the different visual states the button can have)
4. Select the "Pressed" state and edit away to your heats content, visually.

And you're done!

Compare that to trying to edit the raw XAML, as you would have to in VS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by retemplating the button control in blend.

- rclick the control
- edit template
- edit a copy
- modify formatting of constituent components for chosen view states

Comment: Thanx for the reply..but can u suggest something without using blend?

Comment: You can use Blend to either learn how to construct the XAML you want manually, or to create your XAML for you that you can copy / paste. Either way, the best place to start is with Blend. Since it's free with the tools, there's no reason I'm aware of to avoid it alltogether. Since the volume of XAML produced is substantial, I prefer to recommend this approach so you can understand the steps and what you are doing. You also learn how to apply the techniques to other needs.