# How to set the default font or theme for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an app that's design for the black theme, Is it possible to force the black theme on the particular app.

Could I set the default font in my pages to be of a certain size and color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can force it, but it won't pass the certification. Your app should be able work with black and white theme. Try to make your app "theme aware", use StaticResource like PhoneAccentColor. Use this code to detect the theme:

```
public bool LightThemeEnabled
{
  get
  {
    return (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible;
  }
}
```

[Ref](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/16/theme-aware-panorama-background-in-windows-phone-7/)

Comment: I have dark buttons which need a white foreground, how can I alter `{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}`?

Comment: Best way to change buttons appearance it using Visual State http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731858/how-to-change-color-of-button-when-clicked-in-wp7