# Windows Phone : editing DataTemplate's item in code

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate

I have this DataTemplate in my xaml

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="485" d:DesignHeight="166" Height="104" Width="456">
            <StackPanel Margin="92,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock x:Name="nTitle" Text="{Binding title}" FontSize="18.667"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I want to edit TextBlock named "nTitle"'s fontSize attribute in code. I did this but then i don't know what to do:

```
DataTemplate template = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DataTemplate1"];
//template.???
```

Actually i want to increase the fontSize when user pressed a button. Is this a wrong way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be a bad way to do it. If you want to change something when a button si pressed, just redefine the Pressed state in your template. Look at a similiar question: [How to change color of button when clicked in WP7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731858/how-to-change-color-of-button-when-clicked-in-wp7)

Comment: i have no problem with changing color of button when clicked it is different what i said. I have a listbox and every item has an image and a text. It is dataTemplate what decides the text's fontSize. I want to reach that template and change the fontSize of text when a button was pressed.